# Applying depth to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, contour, depth

Apologies if this question has been answered before.

I'm digitizing a historic coastline and would like to add a single depth figure to it in order to merge it with a current contour model. Is there and easy to add depth to the polyline shapefile I am creating?

Comment: Do you have height/depth data for shape file with you ??Few useful link for you http://dmg.caup.washington.edu/Reports/GIS-to-3DS/index.html ,http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/51838-Extrude-shapefile-according-to-height-attribute

Comment: I don't have the data immediately to hand, but the map is from the late 19th century so the low water mark should be easy to extrapolate. I live in the area that I am mapping so tide data is easy to come by.